# Continuum as a Jenkins replacement?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, jenkins, continuum

At our company we're taking a critical look at the products in our Java Development/QA street. One of the products we're looking at is Apache Continuum.

**Could someone with Continuum experience (and preferably also Jenkins experience) explain what the advantages and disadvantages of Apache Continuum are (especially with regards to Jenkins)?**

My first impressions are:

Advantages:

- Better suited for grouping builds and projects (from a UI perspective).

Disadvantages:

- No clear dashboard.
- A relatively small community.
- No plugins (right?).

Comment: SO questions tagged with Jenkins 1142 vs Continuum 14. Prepare to solve issues on your own :-)

Comment: I dont understand how Jenkins is worse at grouping builds. Are the views not enough?

Comment: Thanks, @PetteriHietavirta, that is indeed one of the things which are worrying me.

Comment: Thanks, @Steven, the views do help but Continuum's grouping feels a bit more natural (I'm grasping at straw ehre though ;-)).

Comment: Maybe it's wise to add, Continuum wasn't my suggestion internally, I'm just trying to get a feel for the products and how they relate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We are using continuum and we switched to jenkins.

Jenkins advantages:

- Findbugs
- pmd
- checkstyle
- code coverage (very good chart see for [emma](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/01/emma-plugin-for-jenkins-easy-code.html))
- integration with [artifactory](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+User+Guide)
- integration with [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/)
- post build task (build other projects, automatic archiving)
- new delivery of jenkins every week - critical bugs are solved very quickly
- rpm/deb packages (you can use yum/deb for automatic update every week)

In jenkins you create the view and you can group projects there.

Comment: Thanks, some good points here. I'll wait and see if I can get some more answers. In the meanwhile, could you elaborate on why you stopped using Continuum? Where you unsatisfied with Continuum itself or did Jenkins advantages win you over (i.e. is Continuum good at what it does but does Jenkins offer more or is Continuum a lackluster product in and of itself?)?

Comment: I think reports. See [continuum](http://vmbuild.apache.org/continuum/groupSummary.action) and [Apache Build in jenkins](https://builds.apache.org/) and [code coverage on ebay](https://www.ebayopensource.org/hudson/job/turmeric-ci-runtime/67/cobertura/?) All you have in one place. And integration with sonar/artifactory. You make deploy in artifactory in 30 second when you finish the build (multi module maven project about 40 modules).

Comment: still valid in 2016?

Comment: 2016/05/18 - Apache Continuum has been retired, see https://continuum.apache.org/