# Recommendations for a Continuum Integration, Delivery and Deployment solution

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am reading lots of articles here about the subject and try to find a nice set of tools to integrate and create a Complete CI environment.

Among those articles I particularly liked this one: [Continuum as a Jenkins replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919826/continuum-as-a-jenkins-replacement/9920141#9920141)

I have installed here, but not yet configured because we are doing some testes with GIT and Jenkins.  We have Nexus working fine.

Now I need to have some recommendations to cover the following topics:

- Code Coverage - JaCoCo, Cobertura, Sonar?
- Code Quality Analysis
- PMD, Sonar? ANT, MAVEN, GRADLE?

Maybe I am mixing some concepts here regarding the use of some tools, like SonarQube, if that is the case I am sorry.

So, I am open to "hear" about this.  Thanks

Comment: Could you make this a wiki?  Too broad for single answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Ant, Maven and Gradle are build tools.  You pick one that suites your team. Gradle/Maven may directly work with artifact repos.  Ant will require help from Ivy.
- Coverage:  JaCoCo supports newer Java(7, 8).. Not so much luck with Cobertura
- Sonar: If you can integrate your code with SonarQube that takes care of bit Code Quality Metrics (like Duplicate detection, Findbug , Security ..etc)

**On Jenkins**

You can integrate Jenkins with all of the above tools. You can create Jenkins jobs for practically everything and have tons of plugins to make even simpler. There are more plugins to make Jenkins' based CD easier: [Build Flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) and [workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin).

Comment: Thanks.  I know about Maven and Gradle.  Regarding the others I am not sure how to Stack them to have a full CI environment.  Is it reasonable to have Jenkins + SonarQube (with JaCoCo, PMD and Findbug)?

Comment: Pick Jenkins:  You can always migrate to other tools later (if at all any need)

Comment: Only Jenkins?  No more tools?  What about code coverage, code quality and tests?

Comment: I meant one can use Jenkins and integrate with any of the code  tools.(integration, built, test, deploy,  coverage...etc)